# I'm looking for a way to add two or more timestamps (format "D" 'hh" "mm") together with a formula or VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, time, excel-formula

I am looking for a way to add two timeframes together which results in a "days" "hours" "minutes"-format

[image: Column D calculates the difference in time between columns C and B. This can be done either via a formula or VBA. Column E should generate the sum of D9 and D10.]

As you can see from the picture above:
I can calculate the differences between columns C and B in "days" "hours" "minutes"-format in column D. My goal is now to generate the sum of the D-column in column E.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

**EXTRA**

Formula: `INT(C9-B9)&" D "&TEXT(C9-B9;"h"" u ""m"" min """)`

VBA:

```vb
    Sub Date_Sum()
    
        Dim d1 As Date
        d1 = Range("B9").Value
        d2 = Range("C9").Value
    
        Dim diff As Date
        diff = d2 - d1
    
        ActiveSheet.Range("D5").Value = _
                   CLng(Int(diff)) & " D " & _
                   Hour(diff) & " U " & _
                   Minute(diff) & " min " & _
                   Second(diff) & " s"
    End Sub
```

FYI, the "u" stands for hours in the formula and VBA-code (this is just a translation from dutch where hour is written as 'uur'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

When using the formula and changing the minus to plus, I get a value-error.
When using VBA I can't seem to find a code that works.

Comment: Is it a silly q to ask why you're doing this in VBA if a formula works?
In D9, enter the formula =C9-B9;
Right-click the cell and click 'Format Cells';
Go Number > Custom > enter the format code: hh "u" mm "min"

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this all wrong. Your column D is a string representation, but you don't need to add the strings to get column E.

Columns B and C are already in date formats, which are really just float variables. You can do the math directly with this formula in the cell:

```
=SUM(C8-B8,C9-B9)
```

Once you know the value, you can just reapply your VBA script to pretty print it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: example]

The values in cells are strings. So they can't SUM. Format the cells D8 and D9 and E9 as DATE with format dd hh:mm:ss
After set: D8 = C8-B8,    D9 = C9-B9,    E9 = D8+D9